# Add text beside ionicons

Tags: html, ionic-framework

How to add text beside the ionicons. I only see the ionicons but the text is unable to show.Iwant to show 'More' and 'Less' with the ionicons when user click on it.

Example, preset condition is ion-plus sign and 'More'. Click 'More', it will show ion-minus and 'Less'. Function wise is working. Only 'more and 'less' not shown.

Below is my code

```
<div ng-click="toggleon()" <i class="icon" ng-class="showMore ? 'ion-android-remove-circle assertive' : 'ion-android-add-circle positive'"></i><i class="padding" ng-class="showMore ? 'Less' : 'More'"></i></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-class` is used to apply a CSS class to an element. It cannot be used to apply text. Use `ng-bind` instead. Also use `<span>` and not `<i>` for texts.

```
<div ng-click="toggleon()"> <i class="icon" ng-class="showMore ? 'ion-android-remove-circle assertive' : 'ion-android-add-circle positive'"></i><span class="padding" ng-bind="showMore ? 'Less' : 'More'"></span></div>
```